# How to pass from a function that is below the class to a class that is at the top?

Tags: python, discord

```
class BackButton(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label = 'Назад', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def clan_back(self, button, interaction):
        if user_id == interaction.user.id:
            await interaction.response.edit_message('Вы вернулись назад')

@client.slash_command(name = 'test', description = 'Тест') async def test_command(ctx):
    await ctx.respond('Тест', view = BackButton)
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    return user_id
```

How to pass user_id value to class BackButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `BackButton` class. When you do so, you can add the user ID as a constructor parameter.

```py
class BackButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_id = user_id

    @discord.ui.button(label='Назад', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def clan_back(self, button, interaction):
        if self.user_id == interaction.user.id:
            await interaction.response.edit_message('Вы вернулись назад')

@client.slash_command(name='test', description='Тест')
async def test_command(ctx):
    await ctx.respond('Тест', view=BackButton(ctx.author.id))
```

Now everytime someone does the `test` slash command - a new view gets instantiated with their user ID as a parameter that it'll use to validate who pressed the button.